# Comapare two variable and and echo the missing value

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a variable like below:

```
Variable1="PanicA0 PanicA1"
Variable2="PanicA0"
```

I have to compare variable1 and variable2 and should echo output as `PanicA1` i.e `"PanicA1" is not in Varaiable2`. How can i achieve this using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: split the first variables into an array per word
- Step 2: iterate over the array
- Step 3: Use pattern matching inside double brackets

.

```
Variable1="PanicA0 PanicA1"
variable2="PanicA0"

varArr=($Variable1)
for word in "${varArr[@]}"
do
   [[ $variable2 == *${word}* ]] || echo "$word is not in varaiable2"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the script

```
varone=`echo "PanicA0 PanicA1" | cut -d' ' -f1-`
vartwo=`echo "PanicA0" | cut -d' ' -f1-`

for i in $varone; do
    for j in $vartwo; do
        if [[ $i = $j ]]; then 
            echo "Matched: $i"
            break
        else
            echo "$i is not in vartwo"
        fi
    done
done
```